# c++ error: private expected a ;

Tags: c++, class, private

I'm getting an error on the Private class in my header file. It's saying "expected an ;". Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to c++.

Header:

```
#ifndef CONEMODEL2
#define CONEMODEL2



#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;
class Cone
{

public:
Cone(void);
Cone(double aLength, double aBigRadius, double aSmallRadius, double  aHeight);
~Cone();
void setCone(double aLength, double aBigRadius, double aSmallRadius, double aHeight)
double getCone(void);
double calculateArea();
double calculateVoume();
double displayTheArea();
double displayTheVolume();


private:
double theLength;
double theHeight;
double bigRadius;
double smallRadius;


};
```

Comment: What are you doing when you get the error message? What is the exact error message? Can you give us enough code to replicate the error? (Also, you are in fact missing a semicolon after `setCone`.)

Comment: `void setCone(double aLength, double aBigRadius, double aSmallRadius, double aHeight)` => Missing `;`

Comment: You gen the error message `expected an ;` and the line where this error appears. Really, what more do you want? Open your eyes wide and try to solve yourself these trivial problems.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo:

```
void setCone(double aLength, double aBigRadius, double aSmallRadius, double aHeight);
//                                                                       Semicolon! ^
```

Comment: Cheers I noticed it pretty soon after posting it.